# Render view with parameter in url - NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Could be having a total mind blank here but why when I have the following route will my JS and CSS tried to be rendered with the prefix `/reset`

```
app.get('/reset/:token', (req, res) => {
  res.render('reset');
});
```

So as an example my css tries to pull from `localhost:4000/reset/css` as opposed to `localhost:4000/css`

I have not issues with any other of my views (without the parameter option :token)

Comment: Can you show us the ejs file 'reset'?  I think the problem is probably there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your html/ejs files for the static file links, maybe you forgot to add "/" at be beginning of the relative urls.

Comment: Woopsy, yes I did, what a lemon haha. Thanks for the help